# activator ui only broken, on a mac

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

When running the activator ui on a my mac it crashes and reports the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:224)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:301)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:616)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:641)
at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:757)
at org.jboss.netty.logging.JdkLogger.debug(JdkLogger.java:36)
at org.jboss.netty.logging.InternalLoggerFactory$1.debug(InternalLoggerFactory.java:80)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.<clinit>(SelectorUtil.java:57)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.getMaxThreads(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:248)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.<init>(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:115)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$newBootstrap(NettyServer.scala:47)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$8.apply(NettyServer.scala:127)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$8.apply(NettyServer.scala:126)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:126)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:280)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:275)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:275)
at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(UIMain.scala:110)
at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply(UIMain.scala:110)
at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply(UIMain.scala:110)
at activator.UIMain.withContextClassloader(UIMain.scala:221)
at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:110)
at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:87)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

I did a complete fresh install of the type safe activator. I deleted the .activator, .sbt., .ivy, and .ivy2. I tried a brew install with no luck. The projects run correctly with the normal activator run command but I cannot get the ui to work. I did some more research and some have reported that proxies could be the issue but I have no proxies setup. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you somehow have slf4j configured as the implementation of java.util.logging and then a different slf4j is on the classpath, or something like that.

Here are some docs on how java.util.logging gets configured:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html

I might check environment variables (JAVA_OPTS ? SBT_OPTS ?) and maybe poke around for mentions of slf4j in some file in JAVA_HOME.

Just a guess really...